# Boolean OR and AND problems on CREW and EREW Prams

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

I am learning PRAM algorithms. As we can compute Boolean OR in O(1) time for CRCW PRAM by using following method.

Let A[0]= A[1]|A[2]|A[3]...|A[n] is the Boolean OR of the n bits A[1..n]. Assuming that A[0] is zero to begin with. In the first time step, processor i (1<= i <= n) reads memory location A[i] and proceeds to write a 1 in memory location A[0] if A[i] is a 1. Since several of the A[i]'s may be 1, several processors may write to A[0] concurrently. Hence for CRCW we can compute Boolean OR in O(1) time.

Similarly we can solve Boolean AND for CRCW

I want to know how can we solve this for CREW and EREW. What can be time and processor bounds on algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the exclusive read is not a problem since every processor is reading its own bit. The problem is in the exclusive write part since all of them have to write in A[0]. I think the best way is to make a kind of tournament tree. So you can OR pairs of bit and promote the result to the next level until you have a champion. Then you can write the final result into A[0]. This will be O(log n).

Comment: thanks for reply .. 
SO .. consider we have 5 elements A[0]=1,A[1]=0,A[2]=1,A[3]=1,A[4]=1 . then for CREW and EREW, what we can do is in first time step is.. 
A[0] | A[1] for one processor then A[1] | A[2] for second processor and so on then in next step we can OR their answers right ??? and what can be processor bound then .. is it logn also ???

Thanks

Comment: Exactly, you have to match A[1] | A[2]; A[3] | A[4]; ... ; A[n-1] | A[n], and then their results in the second level and so on. If you want to achieve O(log n) time you will need at least n/2 processors for the first round (which is the number of operations). Then you can reduce in half the number of processors in every step. But this still is O(n) processors because of the first step.